# Large Number - Como pegar o valor

Tags: c++

Eu tenho esse valor

```
v6[0] = 22;
*(_QWORD *)&v6[1] = 42949672960069i64;
```

Tem como eu pegar o real valor desse número ?
O que devo saber sobre isso á respeito de engenharia reversa ?

Como compilar isso no Dev C++ ? Obrigado.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow **in Portuguese** @Vashet . In case you haven't noticed, this is the SO Portuguese community, if you're looking to get help in english please visit the [SO English Community](http://stackoverflow.com). If you're looking to get help in portuguese, please edit and translate your question.

Comment: Obrigado mano. Thanks bro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você precisa saber qual o tamanho do dado que você espera receber.

Veja a tabela com os tipos de dados e o seu respectivo tamanho nessa [documentação](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/cc953fe1.aspx)

Dependendo do tamanho do número que você espera, mesmo ele sendo inteiro, é necessário um long, float, ou double para armazená-lo.

Comment: Pelo que constei, o tamanho do dado é 10. o.O! Como devo prosseguir agora ? :) Tem que ser obrigatoriamente um dos 3 apenas ? Aqui consta long double. Que é double. Obrigado!

Comment: Citei os 3 como exemplo, mas se é necessário o long double, use ele!

Comment: Se eu te disser que nunca mexi com large number você acreditaria ? Bom eu sei definir qualquer variável. É do mesmo jeito que as outras ? Como eu faria definir o valor e o número a ser utilizado ? Ajuda-me !

Comment: é como qualquer outra declaração de variável: "  tipo nome; "

Comment: Apenas para entender, o resultado seria : 42949672960069 ? Usando int64 ? :O

Comment: creio que sim, já que você colocou = 42949672960069i64